# getting filename part of a path in windows batch script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

In a batch script, I have a batch var %filePath% that has the path to a file. If I want to extract just the filename part from it, what is the command for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%filePath%") do set "fileName=%%~nxi"
 echo %fileName%
```